# Postgres convert empty string to NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, postgresql-10, ifnull

I run a Postgres database and would like to convert **empty string** into **NULL**.
The following snipped should do this with all columns, but it isn't working.

```
SELECT * FROM schema.table NULLIF(columnname,'');
```

The error message is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "''"
LINE 2:  NULLIF(columnname,'');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snipped converts empty strings into NULL:

```
UPDATE schema.table SET columnname=NULL where columnname='';
```

This works for me.

Comment: This answer has several limitations. Firstly, it assumes that the `columnname` is already set as nullable in the schema, which may not be the case. Secondly, it only deals with currently existing values, and future select queries on the table may not return the correct results, if the quality of inserted data is not ensured. Thirdly, it was clearly not the OPs intention to run updates on the table, but to convert empty strings to nulls on the fly. -1

Answer (score 5):

The proper syntax is:

```
SELECT . . ., NULLIF(columnname, '')
FROM schema.table;
```

That is `NULLIF()` is a function.  If you want to return the value, then it needs to be used in the `SELECT`.  Just hanging around after the `FROM` clause is not valid SQL.